# How can I make wxTextCtrls in a FlexGridSizer all be 'x' lines high?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have an array, of unknown length, of `key:val` pairs. Each pair occupies a row in a `FlexGridSizer`. The keys are in the first column, as `wx.StaticText`s, and the vals are in the second column, as `wx.TextCtrl`s.

The problem is that there isn't a lot of room available, and some of the vals are relatively long, and don't fit in the `wx.TextCtrl`s. I would like to have all of the `wx.TextCtrl`s be maybe 2 or 3 lines in height.

I've tried using `style = wx.TE_MULTILINE`, but that just adds a vertical scrollbar, as opposed to the default behaviour of scrolling horizontally with left/right/home/end etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `FlexGridSizer`. I made each of the val cells span across two rows, and added empty `wx.Size()`s below each key. The result is something like this:

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use wxGrid.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/overview_grid.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the wx.TextCtrl, you can apply the wx.HSCROLL style to it to make the control have a horizontal scrollbar, but this won't work on GTK1-based systems: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.TextCtrl.html

There's also an ExpandoTextCtrl that you might want to look at: from wx.lib.expando import ExpandoTextCtrl (see the wxPython demo for an example)